# Vimeo - Embed user name in watermark

Tags: video, video-streaming, jwplayer, vimeo

I have this specific requirements. I have premium video content that I would like to host on site like Vimeo. I need in watermark along with company logo, user name who purchased the video. Is this possible?

User name will come from the database. So it has to be dynamically added just before user starts viewing.

How this can be achieved in Vimeo or any other video hosting site.

Regards,
Sanjay

Comment: JW Player doesn't support any third-party suppliers other than YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

We only support YouTube as a 3rd party source - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support